# How to return validation errors back to swift from php or segue on success

Tags: php, swift, alamofire

I am using alamofire to post data to a php script which inserts data into a mysql database. This part is working fine but I have some validation on the server like checking for a valid email address for example. So, here is the swift code:

```
    Alamofire.request(url!, method: .post, parameters: parameters)
        .validate(statusCode: 200..<300)
        .responseJSON { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success:
                print(response)
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }
    }
```

Here is the php that handles the inserting.

```
    if($booking->create($conn)) {

        $response['status'] = "200";
        $response['message'] = "Success";

    } else {

        $response['status'] = "400";
        $response['message'] = $booking->errors;
    }

    echo json_encode($response);
```

In swift, the response in console for failed validation is:

```
SUCCESS: {
    message =     (
        "Invalid email address",
        "Contact number required"
    );
    status = 400;
}
```

If there are no errors, I actually want to segue to another view controller and if there are errors, I want to display them in labels perhaps.

But, initially I just wanted to say if there are any errors, print them and if there are no errors, then segue. But if I try to put an if statement into the response I get an error.

```
 case .success:
    if response == "200" {
    // segue
 }
```

> Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type
>   'DataResponse' and 'String'

Comment: Your backend shouldn't return a success HTTP response code if the request was malformed. It should return 400 in this particular case when the request was malformed. Moreover, `===` is the reference equality operator, `==` is the equality operator.

Comment: @DávidPásztor, edited my question. Not sure if it is correct now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am hoping someone will show me a better way to do this but I have made some progress and it is working. My understanding of the Alamofire documentation is that if you get a response that means it will always be a 200 response no matter what your server sends back. So, the only way I could work around that was to parse the response as json using codable and then do something based on that data, like this:

```
        Alamofire.request(url!, method: .post, parameters: parameters)
            .responseJSON { response in
                let data = response.data
                let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()


                do {

                    let serverResponse = try jsonDecoder.decode(PhpResponse.self, from: data!)
                    if serverResponse.status == "200" {

                        print("Success")

                    } else {

                        print(serverResponse.message)
                    }

                } catch {

                    debugPrint(error.localizedDescription)

                }
        }
```

So, I post the data from swift to the server, do some form validation using php and then using php's json_encode, I send that back to swift in json format and do something based on that response.